# what does the path that in red header area of every rails documentation pages use for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails
when I check the rails online documentation pages 
like this:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

in the red header area

```
ActiveRecord::Base  
In: activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb: activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb: activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb: activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb: activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:
```

what does the path mean?
Do them reference to the related source files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, modules or classes can be defined in several files.

file1.rb:

```
class Foo
  def method1
    :foo
  end
end
```

file2.rb:

```
class Foo
  def method2
    :foo
  end
end
```

interactive ruby console:

```
$ irb
> require 'file1'; require 'file2'
> foo = Foo.new
> foo.method1 => :foo
> foo.method2 => :foo
```

Those paths just list where the ActiveRecord::Base is defined.